# Why does Collectors.toMap report value instead of key on Duplicate Key error?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

This is really a question about a minor detail, but I'm under the impression to get something wrong here. If you add duplicate keys using [Collectors.toMap-method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) it throws an Exception with message "duplicate key ". Why is the value reported and not the key? Or even both? This is really misleading, isn't it?

Here's a little test to demonstrate the behaviour:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestToMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Something> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Something("key1", "value1"),
            new Something("key2", "value2"),
            new Something("key3", "value3a"),
            new Something("key3", "value3b"));

        Map<String, String> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.key, o -> o.value));
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private static class Something {
        final String key, value;

        Something(final String key, final String value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the lazy incredulous, here's the code in [ideone](https://ideone.com/4AqyzH)

Comment: I think it's planned to change in Java 9 (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/b877de2ea2f2/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l129 - note that it's still in development).

Answer (score 30):

This is reported as a bug, see [JDK-8040892](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892), and it is fixed in Java 9. Reading the [commit fixing this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/8b80651ce43f), the new exception message will be

```
String.format("Duplicate key %s (attempted merging values %s and %s)", k, u, v)
```

where `k` is the duplicate key and `u` and `v` are the two conflicting values mapped to the same key.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers already state, it’s a bug that will be fixed in Java 9. The reason, why the bug arose, is, that `toMap` relies on [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which has the signature

```
V merge(K key, V value, BiFunction<? super V,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction)
```

This method will insert the `key`-`value` mapping, if there was no previous mapping for the `key`, otherwise, the `remappingFunction` will be evaluated to calculate the new value. So, if duplicate keys are not allowed, it’s straight-forward to provide a `remappingFunction` which will unconditionally throw an exception, and you’re done. But…if you look at the function signature, you’ll notice that this function only receives the two *values* to be merged, not the *key*.

When the [`throwingMerger`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#132) was implemented for Java 8, it was overlooked that the first argument is *not* the key, but even worse, it is not straight-forward to fix.

You’ll notice, if you try to provide an alternative merger using the [overloaded `toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). The key value simply isn’t in scope at this point. The Java 9 developers had to change the whole `toMap` implementation for the no-duplicate case to be able to provide an exception message reporting the affected key…

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40764505/2711488) contains a work-around. It’s designed for the case where an explicit map supplier is intended, but it’s easy to substitute it with `HashMap::new`, which is equivalent to what the standard `toMap` does in Java 8 and Java 9.

Answer (score 3):

This is a know bug in Jdk 8. The message thrown should either display at least two values for which there is a key collision or ideally the key for which the collision happened. Attached is the [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892) for the same

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, duplicate values from two streams (or with same strems iterating twice) are not allowed to be merged into the Map at a time.
You can use **Collectors.groupingBy** & **Collectors.mapping** to combine the results into the `Map<Object, Set<Object>>`  or 
`Map<Object, List<Object>>` for processing.

```
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(new Employee("Sachin", 40));
    employees.add(new Employee("Sachin", 30));   
    employees.add(new Employee("Rahul", 30));

    Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = employees.stream()
                                    .collect(
                                            Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                                Employee::getAge, 
                                                                Collectors.mapping(
                                                                        Employee::getName,
                                                                        Collectors.toSet()
                                                                )
                                                            )
                                            );
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, I think you should read the question again and also the answers others have provided. Yes, you will receive an Exception if you try to add the same _key_ multiple times. Values are indeed okay. Anyways, my question was about the error message, not the fact that duplicate keys are forbidden in Collectors.toMap. As it turns out, this was a bug which was fixed in later Java versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It was fixed on Java 9.
Message in Java 8.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key HELLO IM NOT A KEY I AM A VALUE #1
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
    at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1253)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at compass.issues.CollectorsToMapMessageIsWrong.main(CollectorsToMapMessageIsWrong.java:31)
```

And Java >=9 the message it's self explanatory.

For example in Java 15 i can get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 1 (attempted merging values HELLO IM NOT A KEY I AM A VALUE #1 and HELLO IM NOT A KEY I AM A VALUE #2)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at java15.CollectorsToMapMessageIsWrong.main(CollectorsToMapMessageIsWrong.java:31)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BinaryOperator<Long> mergeFunction = (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue;
                Map<String, Long> dataTableIdMap = dataTableRepository.findByClientId(clientid)
                                    .stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(DataTable::getAbbreviation, DataTable::getId, mergeFunction));
```

Comment: Well, this is just an example of a merge function, which returns the new value. So later keys would replace former ones, like Map.put. But I think you should read the question again. It was more about the odd error message, which tuned out to be a bug in JDK which was fixed in later versions.

Comment: Yes, But the cause for this is user always expect what is the size of entry list that should be the size of extracted map. because as you know map always work with n->n mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem and are forced to use Java 8 in your project, then you will have to create your own collector to get a meaningful error message.

Below you can find an example of a collector which gives you a meaningful message similar to the one you would get with Java 9:

```
private static class Something {
    private final String k;
    private final String v;

    public Something(String k, String v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    List<Something> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Something("key1", "value1"),
            new Something("key2", "value2"),
            new Something("key3", "value3a"),
            new Something("key3", "value3b"));

    Collector<Something, ?, Map<String, String>> eloquentCollector =
            Collector.of(HashMap::new, (map, something) -> putUnique(map, something.k, something.v),
                    (m1, m2) -> { m2.forEach((k, v) -> putUnique(m1, k, v)); return m1; });

    Map<String, String> map = list.stream().collect(eloquentCollector);
    System.out.println(map);
}

private static <K,V> void putUnique(Map<K,V> map, K key, V v1){
    V v2 = map.putIfAbsent(key, v1);
    if(v2 != null) throw new IllegalStateException(
            String.format("Duplicate key '%s' (attempted merging incoming value '%s' with existing '%s')", key, v1, v2));
}
```

If you run this code, you will see the following error message pointing to the duplicate key and merge values:

> Duplicate key 'key3' (attempted merging values value3a and value3b)

You should get the same exception message if you use in the example above `parallelStream()`, like e.g:

```
Map<String, String> map = list.parallelStream().collect(eloquentCollector);
```

Credits to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for pointing out that the original answer was not OK for parallel streams.

Comment: Your collector still is subject to the original problem for parallel streams, as your merge function just uses the original implementation which will throw an error with the wrong message when there is a duplicate key encountered at this point. For a correct collector, you have to use the fixed function for both, accumulator and merge function, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764505/2711488), given two years ago.

Comment: @Holger Many thanks for pointing this out. I was indeed not aware of your answer which provides a better solution for the same problem. You are right that I my answer does not solve the problem for parallel streams.