# Alternative for throwingMerger in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm implementing own collector that uses *merge function*. Unfortunately, for some of my cases, I can't reuse the following JDK merger function that thrown **IllegalStateException**.

```
java.util.stream.Collectors#throwingMerger
```

It happens due to the fact that it has **private** access modifier and access from other(not inner) classes is restricted. 
However, javadoc says the following:

> This can be used to enforce the assumption that the elements being collected are distinct

But, as I see, java doc is out of date. It can't be used. The question is whether JDK provides access to similar functionality for the java developers(similar method, constant etc) or one should write it on their own?

Comment: It's not really that difficult to write yourself.  I've written it dozens of times (though I'd prefer that I didn't, but that's another matter).

Comment: `(a, b) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); }` there's the whole merger function.

Comment: The javadoc is not out of date. It correctly states that the method can be used by other methods of the class for the described purpose. If you look at the [*generated* javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#method.summary), not the source, you'll see that the method isn't even there. The javadoc is not intended for you, but for the JDK developers.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, if we use proper formatting on this, it will be three lines. It's not very convenient to write it all the time. However, if we make a utility class that should be fine. But, maybe there is an other way around.
Andreas, yes, you're right. They might have left it for other JDK developers.

Comment: Does “that uses *merge function*” imply that you are really using `Map.merge` in your collector?

Comment: @Holger, that's more like it used here:
java.util.stream.Collectors#toMap(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>, java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends U>, java.util.function.BinaryOperator<U>)

Comment: Well, `toMap` uses the merge function to pass it to `Map.merge`, but why do *you* need the throwing merge function?

Comment: I want to implement my own toMap like function.

Comment: Why? And is it using `Map.merge`? As said, that’s the reason the throwing merge function is needed, but when you implement your own collector, you are not forced to use `Map.merge`.

Comment: This method -  

java.util.stream.Collectors#toMap(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>, java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends U>, java.util.function.BinaryOperator<U>, java.util.function.Supplier<M>) 

accepts BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction. I want it to use default merge function without passing it into args and still having ability to use Supplier<M> mapSupplier arg.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `throwingMerger()` is implemented as follows

```
private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> throwingMerger() {
    return (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); };
}
```

You could add a similar method to your code base, but you should be aware of the fundamental problem of that merger: the exception message is incorrect. The first argument to that function is the old value, not the key. The key is not available to this function, so producing an exception message including the duplicate key is impossible for this merge function.

So, since fixing this issue at this place is impossible, it’s good that this function is an implementation detail, so it could be removed for Java 9 without any compatibility constraints.

For providing a reasonable diagnostic, `toMap` without merge function needs an entirely different implementation than `toMap` with (non-throwing) merge function, so the `toMap` and `toConcurrentMap` collectors without merge function have been entirely rewritten.

A common reason for asking for the throwing merge function, is that there is no `toMap` overload accepting a map `Supplier` without the merge function. But since the throwing merger is not going to do the right thing and an entirely different approach is needed when duplicate keys should be rejected, you may use the collector of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764505/2711488) instead. A slightly improved version of it is

```
public static <T, K, V, M extends Map<K,V>> Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper,
        Supplier<M> mapSupplier) {

    return Collector.of(mapSupplier,
            (m,t) -> putUnique(m, keyMapper.apply(t),
                                  Objects.requireNonNull(valueMapper.apply(t))),
            (m1,m2) -> {
                if(m1.isEmpty()) return m2;
                if(!m2.isEmpty()) m2.forEach((k,v) -> putUnique(m1, k, v));
                return m1;
            });
}
private static <K, V> void putUnique(Map<K, V> map, K key, V v1){
    V v2 = map.putIfAbsent(key, v1);
    if(v2 != null) throw new IllegalStateException(
        String.format("Duplicate key %s (values %s and %s)", key, v1, v2));
}
```

Comment: For reference, there is a bug raised against the JDK that the exception message is incorrect - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892, which says that it was fixed in JDK 9

Comment: @Woodz that’s correct; my answer already mentions that the erroneous throwing merger has been removed in Java 9, further, if you follow the link in my answer, you get to a Q&A which discusses the issue, included a link to JDK-8040892 in the accepted answer.