# Absence of toMap method with key, value and map supplier in Collectors

Tags: java, java-8

`Collectors.toMap` has three overloaded variants.

**1. Key and value mapper:**

```
toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)
```

**2. Extending 1 adding a merge function:**

```
toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

**3. Extending 2 with a map supplier:**

```
toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

I wonder why there isn't a method taking a *key supplier*, *value supplier* and *a map supplier*.

This would be useful in cases when I want to use a different map(other than a HashMap) and I know for sure that my key mapping function would not generate duplicate keys.

To achieve this, I either have to pass (a simple) lambda for the *mergeFunction*

```
persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity(),
                (a, b) -> a, 
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

<s>or, use `Collectors.collectingAndThen`</s>

```
persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity()),
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @Holger in the comments, copying into a `LinkedHashMap` won't help as the order has already been changed when populating the map by the toMap method

> [..]collectingAndThen does not achieve the goal, as copying the unordered map into a LinkedHashMap after the fact does not restore the order

Comment: Clearly your second approach achieves the solution and communicates the intent of having a new Map type. Why pollute the API when there is absolutely no need to do so?

Comment: @Avi True. But passing a merge function wrongly indicates to the readers that the source can have duplicate ids (or in general the key mapper can produce duplicate from the source). And the 2nd option is a bit more verbose

Comment: First option I wouldn’t do because it misleads the reader. Second option is precise. Verbosity is often not sufficient reason to pollute an API.

Comment: It is not an unreasonable requirement (Guava's `ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(...)` collector does this); the question is whether this is a useful enough requirement to carry its weight in the standard API. It is too easy to overestimate the usefulness of our own ideas to others (we are all likely guilty of it).

Comment: @Avi `collectingAndThen` does *not* achieve the goal, as copying the unordered map into a `LinkedHashMap` after the fact does not restore the order. But the other variant using `(a, b) -> a` as merge function isn’t equivalent either, as the `toMap` collector without merge function will throw an exception on duplicate keys. The intended behavior can’t be implemented that way, as the merge function doesn’t know the key. That’s a problem, even the JDK developers didn’t realize, so in JDK 8, it produces wrong error messages. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764505/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger Didn't realize the 2nd option won't work as I just focussed on getting the output in a different map type. I didn't understand your last point about the *other variant*. Are you referring to the 1st option? My question is based on that fact that there won't be dups in the key

Comment: @user7 Looks like the second option doesn't work. In that case, the lack of a sufficiently concise equivalent (toMap taking merge functions doesn't throw as toMap without a merge function) might be enough to justify adding another method to the API. At the moment, the best alternative is probably something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090335/5699679) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096750/5699679).

Comment: There is no problem with `(a, b) -> a` when there are no duplicates and you specifically use `toMap` without a merge function when you assume that there are no duplicates. The question is what happens in the erroneous case, i.e. when there is a duplicate despite there shouldn’t. A merge function like `(a, b) -> a` will silently pick one of them and the error stays unnoticed. The two-arg `toMap` collector will throw an exception instead and normally, that’s what you want in the erroneous case.

Comment: @Holger Yes. I intented the *missing method* (with key, value mapper and map supplier) to throw like the two arg toMap.

Comment: Exactly. That’s a missing feature. You may follow the link of my first comment for a solution or well, [this newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45210944/2711488) contains a slightly improved version of it.

Comment: @Holger Great. The summary is, leaving out such a method was not done consciously. Both your implementations for rolling our own method for this would work fine. Though pointing to your answer solves this case, I'm not convinced that this question should be closed as a duplicate to one of the other two questions. If you have a question that would fit as a dupe to this, I'm happy to mark this as a dupe Or, I suggest you to add an answer to this, summarizing your other two answers, and it can act as reference to the future readers.