# Issues with toMap, java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to write this method which should provide a map, having for each entry: the title of the book as key and as value the number of its copies in the collection.

Just to clarify better, `booksColl` is a `TreeMap<String,LinkedList<Book>>`, where the key is the book title and the value a list of books representing its copies.

Eclipse returns this type of error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to SortedMap<String,Integer>`, I don't understand why and how I can solve it, please could you help me?

Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if the question might be stupid.

```
/**
 * Returns the book titles available in the library
 * sorted alphabetically, each one linked to the
 * number of copies available for that title.
 * 
 * @return a map of the titles liked to the number of available copies
 */
public SortedMap<String, Integer> getTitles() {     
    
    SortedMap<String, Integer> res = this.booksColl.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,e->e.getValue().size()));
    return res;
}
```

I tried to cast the toMap parameters but It doesn't work either.

Comment: Just change the type of your variable to `Map<String, Integer>`, which is what `.collect(Collectors.toMap(...))` returns. It doesn't return a sorted map.

Comment: So the problem is related just to the fact that collect does not return a SortedMap?
Adding TreeMap::new as second argument shouldn't be a possible solution too?

Comment: Yes, that is also a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I feel this is the most readable solution

```java
SortedMap<String, Integer> res = new TreeMap<>();
this.booksColl.forEach((key, val) -> res.put(key, val.size());
```

Note that the two args `Collectors.toMap(...)` returns `Map`, not `SortedMap`

```java
Map<String, Integer> res = this.booksColl.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e->e.getValue().size()));
```

If you want a `SortedMap` you'll need to use the four args `Collectors.toMap(...)`

```java
SortedMap<String, Integer> res = this.booksColl.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e->e.getValue().size(), (v1, v2) -> v1, TreeMap::new));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the returned map type to be a `SortedMap`, use the four-argument overload of the `Collectors#toMap`.

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> res = booksColl.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().size(),
                (a, b) -> a,
                TreeMap::new));
```

The third argument is a *merge function* used to resolve conflicts among values with the same key. Since the input source is a `TreeMap`, there won't be any conflicts (as there would be exactly one entry for a book title). Hence, just returning the first of the two values here.

We use the last argument to specify the  type of the Map (`TreeMap` here) into which the results are to be collected into.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem!
I just want to ask you if the third parameter is mandatory to specify what we sort the map by.

Comment: Yes, the third argument is mandatory as [there is no three-arg version with key mapper, value mapper and map supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152547/absence-of-tomap-method-with-key-value-and-map-supplier-in-collectors). The third argument is not used to sort the map. It is a BiFunction to resolve collisions when more than one entry in the source map is being mapped to the same entry in the result map (which won't happen here). The ordering of the entries in the result map is solely determined by the type of the map.

Comment: If you use the zero args `TreeMap` constructor then you will be sorting by the natural order of the keys (ie keys must implement `Comparable`). If you want a custom comparator you will pass `() -> new TreeMap<>(myComparator)` instead of `TreeMap::new`

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand really well the scope of the third argument, you told me it resolve collisions when more than one entry in the source map is being mapped to the same entry in the result map, why doesn't it happen here?
Edit... I was confused I understand now... But if it doesn't happen here, can you explain why we need it?

Comment: Because the set of keys in the result map is the same as in the source. Say we want the result map's key to be the first letter of the book title (`"A"`, `"B"` and so on) and changed the key extracting function appropriately, then we have to provide a valid implementation of the *merge function* (3rd argument) to sum the number of books among all books which start with a letter.

Comment: Here's the code which explains the above comment - https://ideone.com/EVrvT3