# String to Map conversion with Java-Stream and duplicate in values in resulting Map

Tags: java, java-stream

Could you please help me find out better/cleaner solution for next situation:
Web element attributes collected as string in format:

```
animation-delay:0s;animation-direction:normal;animation-duration:0s;
```

Target: create Map<String, String> of attributes and their values.
Note: in attributes value duplicates is possile, 'none' for example.

Current workable solution:
Form list from string -

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(attributes.split(";")).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : list) map.put(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]);
```

But probably it's possible get same result with just one stream, but there is a problem with duplicates. Not in keys, that are not allowed in Map, but also with duplicated values that still threated as keys during Collect operation. For example width and height can both has value 100px and it produces exception in stream.
Solution below - doesn't work...

```
Arrays.stream(attributes.split(";"))
                .distinct()
                .map(entry -> entry.split(":"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry[0], entry -> entry[1]));
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: There’s a [bug in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40039649/2711488); in case of a duplicate keys, the exception message will include the value. However, it still is the key that is actually duplicated. Note that your `distinct()` does not do what you seem to think. When the stream contains `"a:b"` and `"a:c"`, those strings *are* distinct, but you still get an exception due to the duplicate key `"a"` (but Java 8 will report `"b"` or `"c"` in the exception message). But your example input will not cause an exception, despite having two `"0s"` values.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by mapping to some object representing a key-value pair, in the simplest case it can be a list/array of strings, then the pairs are collected into `Map` using `Collectors.toMap`:

```
String attributes = "width:100px;height:100px;animation-delay:0s;"
    + "animation-direction:normal;animation-duration:0s;font-family:Arial;"
    + "font-family:Helvetica;font-family:sans-serif";

Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(attributes.split(";"))
        .map(pair -> pair.split(":"))
        .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // keep only key:value pairs
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            arr -> arr[0], 
            arr -> arr[1], 
            (v1, v2) -> String.join(", ", v1, v2) // merge values if needed
            , LinkedHashMap::new // optional argument to keep insertion order
        ));

map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", k, v));
```

Output:

```
width: 100px
height: 100px
animation-delay: 0s
animation-direction: normal
animation-duration: 0s
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
```

Also the map can be collected with `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.mapping` + `Collectors.joining`:

```java
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(attributes.split(";"))
        .map(pair -> pair.split(":"))
        .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // keep only key:value pairs
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            arr -> arr[0], 
            TreeMap::new, // optional, sort by keys
            Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.joining(", "))
        ));
```

Output:

```
animation-delay: 0s
animation-direction: normal
animation-duration: 0s
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
height: 100px
width: 100px
```

Comment: I’m not sure which problem this answer is trying to solve. The OP claimed that *duplicate values* produced an exception, which is simply not how it works. So there’s no real problem to begin with. Your answer starts with “*This should be done by mapping to some object representing a key-value pair*” but I don’t see such a “key-value pair” in your code. Instead, you just renamed the lambda parameter from OP’s `entry` to `pair`, which doesn’t change the fact that it is just a string, further, you changed the `map` to `flatMap` (in the first version only), which doesn’t work.

Comment: OP's issue was with missing merge function in `toMap` collector; `flatMap` was a typo that should have been removed earlier.

Comment: Well, somehow, yes. After thinking about the question a bit longer, [I got an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481931/66482322?noredirect=1#comment117547755_66481931) where the OP’s conclusion “*Not in keys, that are not allowed in Map, but also with duplicated values that still threated as keys during Collect operation.*” came from. But when your answer is “you need to specify a merge function” you should say exactly that, instead of all the distracting stuff, and not make irrelevant changes to the code.